# Update summary tab formula when a new sheet is added

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to build a formula that updates a Summary Tab formula when I add a new worksheet.

The workbook is used for making capital requests compared against a master budget. Each time a capital request is made a new sheet is required which I'd like to be summed up on the first sheet via a macro/vba.

In sheet 1 (Master Budget) Column M I have 'Approved Capital to Date' which sums Column L in the next worksheet which is the Capital Request. Because there might be 30-40 capital requests over the life of the project, instead of going into the cell on the Master Budget sheet and updating the formuala, It would be easier for users to 'click a button' and ensure the approved to date is capturing each new sheet that is added.

My code sample so far is as follows, but needs some input to make it work!

```
Sub updateApprovedToDate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myF As String
myF = "=SUM("

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

If ws.Name <> "Master Budget" Then
    myF = myF + ws.Range("L10") +

End If

Next
Sheets("Master Budget").Range("M10") = myF
End Sub
```

Many  thanks in advance!

Comment: get rid of `myF = "=SUM("` and change the stuff in the if statement to: `myF = myF + ws.Range("L10")`

Comment: But then myF is not defined?

Comment: Mh? Dont you just want to sum the L10 values from different sheets? That is what the line `myF = myF + ws.Range("L10")` does. Or now that I read it again, do you need your cell M10 on Master Budget to actually have a formula instead of the value?